# Does it make sense to have negative epsilon when tuning a linear-SVM model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I'm using the following tuning code to find the best case and epsilon for my svn model.

```
tuneResult <- tune(
    svm, 
    labels ~ ., 
    data = dataset, 
    ranges = list(epsilon = seq(-5.0, 5, 0.1), cost = 2^(0:3)))
```

But surprisingly it suggests `cost = 4` and `epsilon = -5`!

Then I trained the model using these parameters and tested with `confusionMatrix`. Unfortunately, the model is not as accurate as a model without these parameters.

```
model1 <-  svm(labels ~ ., data = dataset, kernel = "linear", cost = 4 , epsilon = -5)
model2 <-  svm(labels ~ ., data = dataset, kernel = "linear")
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;**

The issue is in your `tuneResult` command, where you allow `epsilon` to vary in the range `[-5, +5]`, which makes no sense as `epsilon` is defined for values `>=0`. The fact that `tuneResult` returns `epsilon = -5` suggests a convergence failure/issue when trying to find an optimal set of (hyper)parameters. Unfortunately, without (sample) data it is hard to get a feeling for any (potential) computational challenges in the classification model.

---

**The role/interpretation of `epsilon`**

Just to recap: In SVMs, `epsilon` describes the tolerance margin (the "insensitivity zone") within which classification errors are not penalised (you should take a look at `?e1071::svm` to find out about the default value for `epsilon`). In the limit of `epsilon` approaching zero from the right, *all* classification errors are penalised, resulting in a maximal number of support vectors (as a function of `epsilon`). See e.g. [here](http://www.svms.org/parameters/) for a lot more details on the interpretation/definition of the various SVM (hyper)parameters.

**Hyperparameter optimisation and convergence**

Let's return to the question *why* the optimisation convergence failed: I think the issue arises from trying to *simultaneously* optimise both the `cost` and `epsilon` parameters. As `epsilon` gets smaller and smaller, you penalise misclassifications more and more (reducing the number of support vectors); *at the same time*, by allowing for greater and greater `cost` parameters you allow for more and more support vectors to be included to counter-balance misclassifications from small `epsilon`s. During cross-validation this essentially drives the model to smaller and smaller `epsilon` and larger and larger `cost` hyperparameters.

**An example**

We can reproduce this behaviour using some simulated data for an SVM classification problem.

1. Let's generate some sample data

   ```
   # Sample data
   set.seed(1)
   x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(10 * 2, mean = 0), ncol = 2),
              matrix(rnorm(10 * 2, mean = 2), ncol = 2))
   y <- c(rep(-1, 10), rep(1, 10))
   df <- data.frame(x = x, y = as.factor(y))
   ```
2. Let's simultaneously tune the epsilon and cost hyperparameters. We use the same ranges as in your original post, including the nonsensical (i.e. negative) epsilon values.

   ```
   # tune epsilon and cost hyper-parameters
   library(caret)
   tuneResult <- tune(
       svm,
       y ~ .,
       data = df,
       ranges = list(epsilon = seq(-5, 5, 0.01), cost = 2^(0:3))
   )
   #
   #Parameter tuning of ‘svm’:
   #
   #- sampling method: 10-fold cross validation
   #
   #- best parameters:
   # epsilon cost
   #      -5    4
   #
   #- best performance: 0.1
   ```

   You can see how the `epsilon` and `cost` parameters tend to their respective minimal/maximal extremes.

Comment: @S.Think PS. More traditionally you would probably optimise the two hyperparameters `gamma` and `cost` (provided you are using a non-linear kernel) with a grid search. Perhaps that is what you were trying to do?

Comment: not really! I was aiming for a linear kernel. That was why I surprised with the negative epsilon. After checking your answer I changed my code and found that cost = 0.19 and epsilon = 0, are the best values. Then I trained my model and got the best accuracy using the confusion matrix. Once again thanks a lot for your help.